# mysql select query doesn't work when trying to select a single row

Tags: php, mysql, row

I am trying to create a php script that selects one row from my table by using the WHERE clause. The problem is the mysql query returns no rows. I know the variable is correct (its user submitted).

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["title"]);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE title ='$title'", $con) 
or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
```

I'm looking for any ideas that could fix my problem. I know the mysql is working properly because other queries execute fine. The title variable is correct; it is passed from a mysql on another page.

ps - I posted a similar question earlier, but worded it poorly and got results that didn't address the problem

Comment: If you remove the link identifier ($con on mysql_query) will it work then?

Comment: Have you tried running the query from within mysql to see if it returns results? Are you receiving errors or is it simply returning 0 rows? What you have shown looks correct so it seems like it is probably an issue with what $title actually is.

Comment: please check the $title value

Comment: echo your query then copy and paste in mysql console, then you will be able to know the error

Comment: the result of the query is "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0007 sec )" so it is working error free but not returning any results. the title variable is the exact same as what is in the database.

Comment: check blank space into title filed from table.

Comment: If mysql is returning an empty result set than the title variable is probably not matching (somehow). Try to run the query in mysql directly in a way you can get the results. Than move it to php. Than move the title into a separate variable.

Comment: @cosmc: obviously not the same, otherwise you would be getting results. If there's so much as a single extra empty space somewhere, it'll make the `=` fail. it may look identical to you ,but it's not identical to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE title ='$title' limit 1") 
or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm new here and I couldn't find the button to comment on the original question.

But you mentioned the request was user submitted. Are they typing it or is it a selection like from a select box or radio button? I'm asking because does the requested title even exist in the DB?

Anyway, what is your result if you use the following?:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE title LIKE '%".$title."%'")
or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
```

If not, then there's definitely no match in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE title like '$title%'", $con)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE title LIKE '%{$title}%'");
```

or maybe this to check formatting:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM links WHERE title LIKE '%%%s%%'", $title);
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had empty space before and after the variable name, like this

```
$query = "select * from user where user_name = ' $user_name ' ";
```

and this results in comparing `userName` with `[empty_space userName empty_space ]` which doesn't exist in the database.

your query should be like this

```
$query = "select * from user where user_name = '$user_name' ";
```